# Eye protection Muay Thai

Tags: muay-thai

I train in Muay Thai for six months now including sparing. I have myopia (-5 / -4.75) and I will get a femto LASIK surgery soon.

My doctor told me that I could resume sparring after 6 weeks as long as I do not get punched in the eyes but I know that I will and that will put me at risk for flap dislocation.

*What should I wear to protect my eyes?*

Are there Special glasses or a type of head gear I can get?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This is a nice question.  I edited it a little to remove some unnecessary information but if I have drastically changed what you wanted, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that is not a problem as long as it was what I meant :)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: don't spar until your doctor says it's okay. Accidents happen.

Comment: My read on their question is more "I plan to not spar for those 6 weeks, but I can't control whether I get hit in the eye after that, so what do I do?"

Comment: I agree with you. There is no point in risking the injury after operation. I was in similar situation and I waited 3 months for my eyes to properly heal before any kind of sparring.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Cary M. Silverman, MD recommends [here](http://www.realself.com/question/long-post-lasik-eye-surgery-goggles-worn-protection) a set of "[rec specs](http://www.adseyewear.com/rec-specs-hs2c/)" the hard-framed sports glasses that you say on, e.g., basketball players. On the same page, Emil Chynn, MD recommends [LASEK](http://www.allaboutvision.com/visionsurgery/lasek.htm#lasekvslasik) surgery instead, which apparently has a lower chance of flap dislocation.

Answer (score 0):

Get PRK or LASEK instead. They'll be cheaper and safer than LASIK (or SMILE) with the only downside being a slightly longer healing period (and the added benefit of leaving your cornea mostly intact). I had SMILE done a year ago and my eyes are still completely f*cked up and I chose SMILE over LASIK because I did MMA at the time and wanted a flapless procedure. I wish I had had PRK instead.

While this topic (Flapless vs. Flap vs. No surgery at all) is hotly debated, actual reliable (unbiased) information is somewhat rare to come by. You might wish to do some research over benefits and downsides of PRK/LASEK vs. LASIK/SMILE/RELEX before making your decision. http://www.expandingknowledge.com/Jerome/HumanBody/Eye/VisionCorrection/LaserSurgery/ProcedureSelection/Main.htm here's to get you started.